# Lost my dividers in Lotus Notes 8.5 mail view

Tags: lotus-notes

I have somehow lost my dividers in Lotus Notes 8.5 mail view.

It used to be that High Priority mail was under that heading, Calendar invites under that heading, and then regular mail below that.  I don't know what happened but those headers are now gone so all of my mail is just in one giant column.

How do I get it sorted again?

UPDATE: someone told me that all I had to do was click on the WHO a time or two, which acts as a sorter.  Done!

Comment: Perhaps you have clicked on one of the columns to enable sort on that column?

Comment: Please answer your own question using the button below.

Answer (score 4):

its not exactly in the "Who" button. You have to click in the little mail envelope icon that is at the left of the Who icon. With this you can get your mails sorted again by High Importance at the top, then Calendar Events and finally regular mail.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Open the window as far wide as you can and they should come back.  Then, make sure your "Who" column is narrow enough, otherwise it pushes your "Subject" colum into the "Who" column which for some reason gets rid of all of the headings.

Answer (score 0):

Click on View, Customize this view, check the width setting on the columns. Had this happen to user who inadvertently dragged subject in front of Who and got the Icon width setting to 100. Changed back to 1 and voila!